# color of svg not appearing in png version

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, colors

so I have a style in the svg image and I am using that to change the fill using javascript with a  random colors function and that works fine. but when I need the svg to be in png format after the color is changed, the changed colors colors are not retained for the PNG but the original colors are kept instead

```
<style type="text/css">
:root{
    --back:#662D91;
    --shadow:0.28;
    --highlight:#F3B4AE;
    --stomach:#EA8A82;
    --lightHigh:#FEE9E5;
    --lasso:#9B5D12;
    --gloves:#29A6DE;--glovesStroke:#000674;--gloves2:#29A6DE;--gloves3:#1C7FC9;--gloves4:#1D7DC6;--gloves5:#1C7DC4;
    --hatBelow:#DB8556;
    --hatBelow2:#8A3C13;
    --hatInner:#8C4017;
    --hatInner2:#934A24;
    --hatInner3:#9D5C3A;
    --stripe:#8A7454;
    --stripeEnd:#382000;

}
    .st0{fill:var(--back);}
    .st1{opacity:var(--shadow);}
    .st2{fill:var(--highlight);}
    .st3{fill:var(--stomach);}
    .st4{fill:var(--lightHigh);}
    .st5{fill:var(--lasso);}
    .st6{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter);}
    .st7{filter:url(#Adobe_OpacityMaskFilter_1_);}
    .st8{clip-path:url(#SVGID_3_);mask:url(#SVGID_4_);fill:url(#SVGID_5_);}
    .st9{opacity:0.7;clip-path:url(#SVGID_3_);fill:url(#SVGID_6_);}
    .st10{fill:url(#SVGID_10_);}
    .st11{fill:#FFD2B3;}
    .st12{fill:#EEBD9C;}
    .st13{fill:#FFE3CE;}
    .st14{fill:#AF7B6E;}
    .st15{fill:var(--gloves);stroke:var(--glovesStroke);stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st16{fill:var(--gloves2);}
    .st17{fill:var(--gloves3);}
    .st18{fill:var(--gloves4);}
    .st19{fill:var(--gloves5);}
</style>
```

this is the style element in my svg and I am changing it using this

```
  root.style.setProperty('--back',colors[0]);
```

the colors is  an array of colors that I get my randomly making a color using a script in the svg
help plz
so this is how i am converting svg to png

```
<script>
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var DOMURL = self.URL||self.webkitURL||self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([svgString],{type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function(){
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="'+png+'"/>';
DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
};
img.src = url;
</script>
```

Comment: You should probably describe how you're converting SVG to PNG because that seems to be an important bit of context

Comment: yea that would help lol

Comment: presumably because you're not serializing the CSS you're using to override the colouring.

Comment: how do i do that and what is it

Comment: @cotneit I included it if there is something thata you can help plz do im really stuck

Comment: what is the `root` element you're setting styles for?

Comment: that is  just accessing the root in the css with `var root = document.querySelector(':root');` @cotneit

Comment: Thanks for the info! Managed to reproduce the issue and published an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Took a minute to thing about it, and it makes sense that it doesn't work. `svg` blob only includes `svg` tag contents and hence has no idea there's a CSS variable set on `html` tag outside of it. Styles applied with `:root` are defined within SVG, so when you yank it out of HTML context, I assume `:root` points to the `svg` tag itself.

Not sure why it works this way, but when using canvas CSS variables set on ancestors of `svg` tag seem to be ignored. What you can do to fix this is set inline styles on either `svg` tag itself or its children.

Here's a reproduction with a fix, don't mind changes to the JS code, it does the exact same thing yours does just but sets CSS variable on `svg` tag instead of `html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SVG thingy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg
      viewBox="0 0 10 10"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <style>
        :root {
          --color: red;
        }

        circle {
          fill: var(--color);
        }
      </style>

      <circle
        cx="5"
        cy="5"
        r="4"
      />
    </svg>

    <canvas></canvas>

    <div id="png-container"></div>

    <script>
      const root = document.documentElement; // html tag
      // root.style.setProperty('--color', 'black'); // Doesn't work

      const svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');
      svgElement.style.setProperty('--color', 'black'); // Works
      
      const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));
      const svgBlob = new Blob([svgElement.outerHTML], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
      
      const canvasElement = document.querySelector('canvas');
      const ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
      
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        const png = canvasElement.toDataURL('image/png');
        document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="' + png + '"/>';
        URL.revokeObjectURL(png);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```